# How to get the expired candidates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I am having a table with the columns for `expired_date` and `registered_date`. 
Expired date have set for 2 days to registered date.

Its look like this:

```
+--------------+--------------+---------------------+
| candidate_id | date_expires | date_added          |
+--------------+--------------+---------------------+
|            1 | 2016-03-26   | 2016-03-24 14:42:18 |
|            2 | 2016-03-23   | 2016-03-21 15:43:40 |
|            3 | 2016-02-15   | 2016-02-13 14:53:30 |
|            4 | 2016-02-22   | 2016-02-20 14:54:19 |
+--------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

My question is, I want to select expired profile to current date and time.

This is how I tried it, but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE date_added = DATE_ADD(date_added, INTERVAL 2 DAY);
```

Hope somebody may help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: what you are trying to match: x = x + 2.

Comment: isn't it supposed to be like this: you should compare the `date_expires` against the current date?

Comment: @1000111 yes I want to it like that

Comment: Please check the `EDIT` section in my answer.

Comment: @1000111, just I checked. Thank you.

Comment: Please also check the `NOTE` section in my answer. It might be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try any of the following query which meets your need.

```
SELECT 
*
FROM candidates
WHERE date_expires < CURDATE();
```

**Or if you want to get the expired accounts with respect to `date_added` field then follow the query given below:**

```
SELECT 
*
FROM candidates
WHERE DATE_ADD(date_added, INTERVAL 2 DAY) < CURDATE();
```

---

**EDIT:**

For fine-grained comparison you may use the following query:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM candidates
WHERE TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,2,date_added) < NOW();
```

**Note:** Actually you don't need to store the expired dates in database. Rather you can store the `profile life time` (in this case it is `2 Days`) in database if this `profile life time` varies across different accounts. You don't need to store this in database if it's constant in nature (i.e. Always `2 DAYS`).

So if you want to bring this change in your table structure then it would look like below:

```
+--------------+--------------+---------------------+
| candidate_id | days         | date_added          |
+--------------+--------------+---------------------+
|            1 | 2            | 2016-03-24 14:42:18 |
|            2 | 5            | 2016-03-21 15:43:40 |
|            3 | 3            | 2016-02-13 14:53:30 |
|            4 | 10           | 2016-02-20 14:54:19 |
+--------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

You need a modified query for this change.

Here it is:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM candidates
WHERE TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,days,date_added) < NOW();
```

Comment: how to do it, if expired date is 4 months

Comment: Then you need two columns. One will hold the `UNIT (i.e. DAYS/MONTHS/YEARS)` and another will hold the `VALUE (i.e. 1/2/3...etc.)`. If you are interested then I can explain better in my answer later.

Comment: Or you can always store the `profile life time` in `DAYS`. That would be better. You need to convert `month/year` into `days`.

Comment: Sorry... I went to lunch... yes I am really interest about this? can we have a chat?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for this

```
SELECT * 
  FROM candidates 
 WHERE date_expires < NOW();
```